# How do I turn on optimization in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, optimization, build

I have some Swift code in Xcode 7.2 that runs well, but when I run `swift -O main.swift` from a command line to run an optimized build of it, my code runs really fast.

How do I turn on code optimization in Xcode? I've tried Product -> Build For -> Running, but that isn't running it at optimized speed. I don't see anything in the project settings for "enable optimization" or "make a release build".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you select `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`, then target the Run scheme, you'll see that it has two build configurations:

- Debug: Builds with option `-O0` for no optimization.
- Release: Builds with option `-Os` for fastest/smallest optimization.

You can find those values in the project's Build Settings, under **Apple LLVM 7.0 - Code Generation, Optimization Level**.

One option is to edit the Run scheme's build configuration, which defaults to Debug, and change it to Release.

Another option is to build for profiling which defaults to Release, and will build an optimized version that can be profiled.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! (One small detail: it's the "Product" menu, not the "Project" menu, and reddit wouldn't let me fix that because it's fewer than 6 characters.) Seems odd to have to change a configuration setting to go between debug and optimized builds. Another question, though - why is it that when I select Product -> Build For -> Profiling and then I run it (or "Run Without Building"), it doesn't run an optimized build, even though the Profile scheme is set to build configuration "Release"?

Comment: @BrianKendig Fixed, thanks!  By default, "Run Without Building" uses the Run scheme and app built in `Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos`, while "Profile Without Building" uses the Profile scheme and app built in `Build/Products/Release-iphoneos`.  Running generally means debugging (which would be hindered by optimization), while Profiling and Archiving deal with the release (optimized) build.

Comment: Ah, I thought "Run Without Building" meant "run the most recent build, no matter how you built it." I wasn't aware that it keeps track of separate Run and Profile builds. Thank you again!

Comment: @BrianKendig Not separate Run and Profile builds, but separate Debug and Release builds.  If Run and Profile were both set to use the Release configuration, they would both share the same build.  NP!