# Could Xcode affect app performance while debugging?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, metal

I have an application written in Swift on SceneKit + Metal. When I build and run the app from Xcode fps counter shows 40fps. But if I run the app myself by tapping the icon on springboard fps counter shows 60fps. How could it be? Could Xcode somehow affect app performance while debugging? I have no idea how this all works, but I suppose there could be some hooks for debugging to work correctly which affect performance. If so, can I opt-in from this?

I'm aware of different build flags for debug and release builds, but I don't make release build. Performance differs in the same debug build while running from Xcode vs when I run the app manually on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experimented with different options in scheme editor and have find out that `Debug executable` checkbox affected performance in my case. So my assumption about debugger was right, but I didn't know about that checkbox before.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Xcode enables the Metal validation layer. That does a bunch of additional checking of how you're using it to catch incorrect uses. The additional checking is slow, which is why Metal doesn't do it unless validation is enabled.

This can be changed in Xcode's Scheme editor. This is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH8-SW3) in Apple's Metal Programming Guide.

Answer (score 2):

[A nice tutorial on iOS Assembly](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2705-ios-assembly-tutorial-understanding-arm). This might be insightful on the topic

> As stated, this is because the compiler is in debug mode, meaning no optimizations are made. If you turn optimizations on, then you’ll see a much smaller function generated.

And also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498390/10424313) about changing optimization levels.